# How to set the default SQLQuery.sql template

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When you open SSMS and your database it defaults to a blank SQLQuery1.sql form that is a blank temp file.  But I want it to always default to a SQLQuery form I already have all my queries on.  So where is the SSMS setting to not use a blank template but use a SQLQuery form that is already saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by editing the file (SQLFile.sql) at the following location (could vary based on installed version):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\SQLFile.sql

Open the file in any editor using administrator mode and you can set the template of your choice.

[image]

Please find more details related to templates **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/template/templates-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)** and **[here](https://www.bisend.com/blog/get-customized-new-query-windows-from-management-studio)**.

Comment: Thanks, that was enough information to help me figure it out because my file was in a different location:


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\SQLFile.sql